# Google Analytics EasyTracker doesn't work in Android app with "falling back to local store" error

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

I'm using EasyTracker (Google Analytics 2.5) in an Android app and can't get it to work.

Here is the logcat log (for the GAV2 tag)

```
Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
................
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
Thread[Failed Connect,5,main]: falling back to local store
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
...............
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: sent 1 of 1 hits
```

The Google Analytics website shows zero events and zero users for the app (over several weeks).

The first logcat error "Need to call initialize" is unclear because there is no initialize method in the EasyTracker class and because other EasyTracker methods don't seem to be hindered by the first error.

The second logcat error "falling back to local store" seems to indicate the problem, but I'm not sure how to debug the problem. The ga_trackingId is correct and I've verified that the id uses dashes (the xml file has tools:ignore="TypographyDashes and Eclipse preferences are set to ignore TypographyDashes issues)

fwiw I noticed that Google has released a V3 version of the library and (in a local build) I've also tried using that library. With V3, I don't see any logcat entries except for one GAV3 tagged entry that says "Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found". (this entry is expected since I'm not tracking any campaigns)

In both cases (2.5 and 3), the code is fairly simple with EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this); in onStart, activityStop in onStop and just one call to tracker.send (V3) or tracker.sendEvent (V2.5). analytics.xml is also simple, so I don't know where the error could be.

Does anyone have any debugging suggestions ?

Comment: have you confirmed that there is no network issue and your app can correctly communicate over internet to google analytics server? are you seeing anything in realtime report in analytics page?

Comment: no network issues, the app is able to make HTTP requests to other sites. Realtime page says 0 users and 0 screenviews

Comment: Interestingly, a new app (with V3 Google Analytics SDK) works fine. Analytics data is getting recorded correctly. However, the same code (with V3 SDK) doesn't work in the first app. 
The difference between the old app and the new is that (a) the two apps have two different ga_trackingIds and (b) the old app originally used the 2.5 SDK.

Comment: Looks like EasyTracker is no longer available in Google Analytics v4. I do not see it in the Google Play Services library project.